# Why does Windows Identity AspNetRoles have Discriminator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, windows-identity

I implemented `Windows Identity` into my application and using EF Migrations the appropriate `[AspNet*]` tables were added to my database. As typical in this scenario, I created an `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from `IdentityUser`. My 'ApplicationUser' class does not have any additional properties. *And at that point in time I did not touch any code or classes related to Roles.*

Now I am looking to add roles so I followed the same pattern as before. I created an 'ApplicationRole' class that inherits from 'IdentityRole' but did not add any addition properties.

However, and this is where my question comes in, EF migrations is trying to create a `[Discriminator]` column for the `AspNetRoles` table. Yet it never created one for the `AspNetUsers` table in the previous migration.

I understand the purpose of the Discriminator column so I am not questioning why it is there. I just do not understand why it is adding it for one table and not the other when both base classes were inherited by the "application" equivalent classes.

The only plausible reason I can think of is because the **original** `IdentityRole` class was used in the **earlier** migration and now I am trying to add a **new** migration that uses the base class. If so, is there a way to get EF to ignore this? There are no plans to ever create multiple classes that inherit from the base nor will I be using the base directly so the `Discriminator` will always contain the same value.